# Unit testing where you depend on implementation of another method

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am implementing a [gap buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer) and am trying to write a test for the insert method, the test currently looks something like this:

```
gapBuffer.insert('a')
assertEquals(gapBuffer.getText(), "a")
gapBuffer.insert('c')
assertEquals(gapBuffer.getText(), "ac")
gapBuffer.insert('d')
assertEquals(gapBuffer.getText(), "acd")
gapBuffer.moveCursorTo(1)
gapBuffer.insert('d')
assertEquals(gapBuffer.getText(), "abcd")
```

Now the problem is that this method is not just testing the insert method because it depends on the correctness of the `getText()` and `moveCursorTo()` methods

Note: the `getText()` and `moveCursorTo()` methods are not trivial but do have tests of their own

Comment: what makes you think that's a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually hard to test a setter without a getter and vice versa. [Back Door Manipulation](http://xunitpatterns.com/Back%20Door%20Manipulation.html) in *xUnit Test Patterns* discuss this in detail.

Some smells from the same book/site:

- [Eager Test](http://xunitpatterns.com/Assertion%20Roulette.html#Eager%20Test): A single test verifies too much functionality.
- [Missing Assertion Message](http://xunitpatterns.com/Assertion%20Roulette.html#Missing%20Assertion%20Message): A test fails. Upon examining the output of the Test Runner, we cannot determine exactly which assertion had failed.

I'd create at least three tests from the one above:

```
@Test
public void testInsert() {
    gapBuffer.insert('a')
    assertEquals(gapBuffer.getText(), "a")
}

@Test
public void testInsertTwice() {
    gapBuffer.insert('a')
    gapBuffer.insert('c')
    assertEquals(gapBuffer.getText(), "ac")
}

@Test
public void testMoveCursorToAndInsert() {
    gapBuffer.insert("acd")
    gapBuffer.moveCursorTo(1)
    gapBuffer.insert('d')
    assertEquals(gapBuffer.getText(), "abcd")
}
```

It helps [Defect Localization](http://xunitpatterns.com/Goals%20of%20Test%20Automation.html#Defect%20Localization).